# Online database of SQL

Tags: sql

Is there an online database with data in it, where I can practice the queries?

Comment: Plenty, for instance http://dbfiddle.uk/ and you could create your own data using simple CREATE TABLE/INSERT INTO. Or [SEDE](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/new) with SO data

Comment: I work with SQLfiddle, but I dont want to create my own data. So looking for something already built.

Comment: And of course you didn't check SEDE. This is very sad, that new users don't even care to take a look.

Answer (score 0):

You can download Oracle SQL developer and practice SQL queries [SQL DEVELOPER](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/sql-developer/downloads/index.html)

and for online SQL you can use this link [Oracel Live SQL](https://livesql.oracle.com/apex/livesql/file/index.html)